# Difference between values and literals

Tags: dynamic, static, literals

What's the difference between values and literals? Values apparently have dynamic type, and literals apparently have static type, according to slide four of the first page in [Here](http://www-inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/~cs61b/fa13/lectures/lect8-2x2.pdf). But isn't a literal a value?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16327483/whats-the-difference-between-a-boolean-literal-and-a-boolean-value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the terms used in that slideshow - a literal is kind of container, so it'll be better to compare between values and containers.

A container "contains" a value. If you write `int x=1;`, then `x` is a container and the number one is a value. But `1` is also a container - more precisely, a literal. The slideshow stress that there is a difference between the value one and the literal `1`.

When you code, you can't actually access values directly - you can only do it via containers. That's why you can write `x` and `1`, but not the value that is the number one.

A literal is a container that can be translated directly to a value without looking at it's surrounding - for example `1` can be translated directly to the number one. `x` can not be translated to a value in such a way, since it's a variable and we don't know what it holds unless we look at the surrounding code.

As for the dynamic vs static types - a container has a static type, known at compile-time. If it's a variable, it's the declared type of the variable. If it's an expression, it's the inferred type of the expression. If it's a literal, it's the direct type of the literal. The compiler can tell the type of each container without running the program and without caring what values it'll hold once the program runs.

A value, on the other hand, is stored in memory as a series of bytes. The type data is also stored in memory near the value(unless it's a primitive value), that's why the types of values are dynamic - because if you want to discover what type a value has, you have to look in the memory during runtime.

Even though values' types are dynamic, Java is a static language since you usually don't look at the dynamic type. Since you can only refer a value via a container, the static type of the container is used when you do things with the value.