# Determine the Selected Index number of a drop down menu?

Tags: javascript, html, indexing, drop-down-menu, selectedindex

I'm trying to make sure that the user is not selecting the default of a drop down method by determining the index number selected. It seems to be only returning false even though I believe the code is correct... So far I have the code listed below but its not working, any ideas?

```html
<p id="Gender">
   <label for="Gender">Gender: </label>
   <select required>
   <option disabled selected value="Select">Select</option>
   <option value="Male">Male</option>
   <option value="Female">Female</option>
   </select>
  </p>
```

```js
 function validate1() { 
  valCheck3 = true;
 var dropD1 = document.getElementById("Gender");
 var resultSelect = dropDown1(dropD1);
 var image3 = getImage(Boolean(resultSelect), "gender");
 var labelGender = getNotification3(Boolean(resultSelect), "gender");
 document.getElementById("Gender").appendChild(image3);
 document.getElementById("Gender").appendChild(labelGender);
  }
  
  function dropDown1(select){
 if(select.selectedIndex > 0){
  return true;
 }
 valCheck3 = false;
 return false;
  }
```

EDIT: I added the HTML I used the setting to make the answer required, the problem is I need to have a button that checks whether the answer has been selected to insert an image next to the box. So in this case I figured I could determine the selected index number of the drop down so that I could determin

Comment: show your html and js

Comment: post a bit of your html snippet, so that it can be reproduced easily.

Comment: There's no reason to wrap `true` or `false` in `Boolean()` unless your functions expect a `Boolean` object rather than a Boolean value for some reason. See for example [What's the difference between a boolean literal and a boolean value?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16327483/215552)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the `required` attribute to the select element, then add some `value` attribute to each option except for the first one (use `value` without the value itself i.e. value="1")
Then you can just use select.checkValidity(), which returns true or false.

Comment: I added those and it definitely makes it look a lot better the problem is I need to determine the selected index of the drop down to be able to determine if I should set an image next to the drop down. So in this case I figured I could just determine the selected index. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

> I'm trying to make sure that the user is not selecting the default of a drop down

You can just add `disabled` attribute to the `<option>` and also make it default. If the user opens the dropdown, the default option can not be clicked anymore and the user has to choose an onther option.

Example:

```html
<form action="">
    <select required>
        <option disabled selected value>Default option</option>
        <option>Option 1</option>
        <option>Option 2</option>
        <option>Option 3</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: In this case, user can still click on submit and move forward, I think the question is to validate the input and show a notification when the user selects first/default value.

Comment: @vS12 You are correct! I added a required to the select, so the default and disabled option can not be submitted